# prove the well ordering principle using the stronger mathematical induction

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, solution-verification, induction

> if $A$ is any nonnull set of natural numbers so $A$ must have a smallest number.

my attempt:

we can write the above statement in a mathematical form ;

if $A \neq \emptyset $$\Rightarrow$$A$ have a smallest number $ (*)$

no we can prove $ (*)$ by proving that:

**$A$ have  not a smallest number $\Rightarrow$$A$ =$\emptyset $**

now let's suppose $B=\{1,2,3,...,n,...\} $ is the set of all natural numbers,and $A$ is a set that have not any smallest number.

now $P(x)$ means that $\{1,...,x\}\in B\setminus A$

$P(1)$ is true because $1$ is in $B$ but not in $A$  (because if it is in $A$, then $A$ have a smallest value)

suppose that $P(k)$ is true ,then the set of numbers  $\{1,...,k\}$ is in $B$ but not in $A$,so we can  say that $K+1 $ is in $B$(because $B$ is the set of all natural numbers),now because$\{1,...,K\}$ is not in $A$, then $ k+1$ will not be   in $A$(because if it is, then $A$ have a smallest value $k+1$). so $k+1$ is in $B$ but not in $A$,that's means $P(k+1)$ is true whenever $P(k)$ is true.

so after the stronger mathematical induction we can say $P(x)$ is true for any natural numbers $x$,which is implies that A have not any element so $A = \emptyset $.

so now i think i prove that:$A$ have  not a smallest number $\Rightarrow$$A$ =$\emptyset $.

which is equivalent to  $A \neq \emptyset $$\Rightarrow$$A$ have a smallest number

-does my proof is true?

Comment: Your solution is totally fine.